# How to access the file name and its detail from directory in the laravel framework?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

```
Storage::disk('local')->files();

Storage::disk('local')->lastModified();
```

I want both thing simultaneously on single line. Can you please tell me how to do so?

Comment: Why? Those are 2 different filesystem operations. What do you think you'd benefit from that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to loop though the files and then get the modified time for each item. If the directory is large, this approach would not be recommended:

```
foreach ( Storage::disk('local')->files() as $file ) {
    dump( $file, Carbon::createFromTimestamp( Storage::disk('local')->lastModified($file) )->format( 'jS M Y, H:i:s' ) );
}
```

Remember to include the following lines at the top of your class:

```
use Storage;
use Carbon\Carbon;
```